# Unable to set screen resolution for Windows 11 when host is Ubuntu (23.10)

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtual box on ubuntu and trying to set up guest additions for windows 11.
When I adds it from devices menus it says this:

[image]

When I continue,  the downloading of iso file is stuck.

[image]

But when I manually adds the iso file add installs it but I still cannot get the option of changing the resolution.

[image]

```
Ubuntu version (Host): 23.10 
Virtual Box version: 7.0.12
Ram Allocated: 4gb
Processors Allocated: 4
Video memory: 128mb
```

How to fix? (I want to change the resolution of virtual machine running windows 11)

Comment: I don't know but i automatically worked without a single change.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you've solved the problem of installing the guest additions.

Your second problem is: screen resolution on guest Windows machine. You can do this on a guest Windows 7 machine by:

1. Click on Start menu button, and search for ***resolution***
2. A list will appear, click on **Adjust screen resolution**
3. Select the desired screen resolution, and **apply**, **Keep changes**, and then **OK**.

The VirtualBox machine will automatically adjust to this resolution. You should also be able to search in the start menu in Windows 8, 10, or 11.

On Windows 11:

- Select **Start  > Settings > System > Display**
- Scroll down to **Scale & layout**, select resolution of choice from **Display Resolution**.